# visual-studio-code дубль строки

Tags: строки, visual-studio-code, дублирование

долго мучался без этой функции - дублировать строки и целые куски кода очень нужно)

Answer (score 1):

методом тыка нашел как сделать дубль строки, на которой сейчас стоИт курсор: `ALT+SHIFT+↓`

З.Ы. с выделенным текстом тоже работает, вдруг кому пригодицца